# How to change inner text of instantsearch components?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-instantsearch

I am using InstantSearch components to implement search on my web app and everyting works just fine, now I wonder, how to change inner text of the components that I've just imported to my project?

For example, my own component looks like this: (of course there are imports and class)

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="searchform-filters">

                <div className="searchform-filter-row1">
                    <Brand searchState={this.props.searchState} />
                    <Type searchState={this.props.searchState} />
                </div>

                <div className="searchform-clearall">
                    <ClearAll />
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

And for example "< ClearAll />" component produce a button with "Clear All" text. I just want to change it, but it's imported from node_modules. What should I pass to this component or how could I change it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fork their code, and build your own component

Comment: Seems like a too much work for such a small change.

Comment: https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/blob/c2dbfe6cdfa89268342fa95ab532063e84f49a57/packages/react-instantsearch/examples/react-native/src/Filters.js Line151 Don't think it supports any property, but you can easier change it yourself.

Comment: Hm, I'm quite disappointed, but I'll try to change it dynamically with JS rather than creating my own components. Anyway, thank you @FisNaN for the reference.